# Saving VS Code settings

Tags: visual-studio-code

I recently downloaded VS Code. I have recommended it to a colleague. I want to send her all my configuration settings so she can just upload them to her VS Code program and enjoy the same shortcuts and option settings. Is there a way for me to save my settings?

I searched the Help file under the word *Workspace *because several programs use this term for saving personal settings. I didn't find what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

VS Code stores your settings in a file called "settings.json", which you can access by opening the Command Palette (Ctrl+Shift+P on Windows or Cmd+Shift+P on Mac) and searching for "Preferences: Open User Settings". Alternatively, you can access this file by clicking on the gear icon in the bottom left corner of VS Code and selecting "Settings".

Once you have opened the settings file, you can copy all of the content to a text file and send it to your colleague. They can then open their own "settings.json" file and replace its content with your settings.

Alternatively, you can use the "Settings Sync" feature in VS Code, which allows you to sync your settings across multiple devices and share them with others. To use this feature, you need to sign in with your Microsoft account and enable "Settings Sync" in the VS Code settings. You can then upload your settings to the cloud and share the sync URL with your colleague so they can download your settings directly to their VS Code program.

To access the "Settings Sync" feature, open the Command Palette and search for "Settings Sync: Turn on". You can then follow the prompts to sign in and enable syncing. Once you have uploaded your settings, you can access the sync URL by searching for "Settings Sync: Share Settings" in the Command Palette.

Comment: That answered my question, Benjii. Many thanks!

Comment: Happy to hear it helped! Have fun with it, and if you found the answer useful, please flag it as the right answer so others can benefit from it :)

Answer (score 0):

Visual studio code stores all it's settings in one big json file, you can access it by pressing <kbd>control</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>p</kbd> and goinf to `Preferences: Open User settings (JSON)`, then press <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>r</kbd> to open it in file explorer. Now you can send her that file.
On top of that you may also want to share your extentions, you can do this by pressing <kbd>control</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>p</kbd> and entering `Extentions: Open Extentions Folder`, this you can also send her.
Edit:
It seems there also is a `keybindings.json` file, you can access this by going to `Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)`.
There also is a `Preferences: Open Default settings (JSON)` command, useful too.